# How to create an offline apk (without using expo publish or hosting assets somewhere) using expo managed workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

I created an app using expo-managed workflow. The app does not call any API or load any external data from the internet. Also, I don't need any OTA. But with expo, some files are needed to load by the internet. Is there any way I can build a fully offline app without expo relying on manifest.json files on its servers?
My main goal is to bundle all assets (images, svgs, ttfs) into the standalone app, without needing to run `expo publish` or hosting assets on my own server.

Comment: this is not really a big deal, just do not connect to anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
For Expo, some files will be loaded over the internet like images etc. The maximum you can achieve is to build a standalone app using turtle-cli. It still requires you to publish the project on Expo or your own server (even a local server) and turn off OTA from `app.json`. If you used a local server to build, you could turn it off, and your app will still work. If you want truly native-like app better use React-Native.